# Lubuntu Precise - Power button doesn't shutdown immediately anymore

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, shutdown, acpi, headless

After some upgrade, my headless lubuntu 12.04 stopped shutting down on power button press.
I tried to edit ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml without success. Nowhere docs on possible alternative to  lubuntu-logout (XF86PowerOff event).

There is another way to shutdown immediately?

Could I set a timeout to logout GUI panel?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm slightly confused at your question regarding the GUI panel on a headless server. So I'm going to ignore it and refer to the "headless server" part.

Check the /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn script:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

You can try editing the /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh script to simply shutdown.

If you make changes to these files, make sure you issue

```
sudo service acpid restart
```

Before trying them.

A potentially helpful thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020630